# How does Dependency Injection work in this case?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

In a Spring Boot Web Application layout, I have defined a Service Interface named `ApplicationUserService`. An implementation called `ApplicationUserServiceImpl` implements all the methods present in `ApplicationUserService`.

Now, I have a Controller called `ApplicationUserController` that calls all the methods of ApplicationUserServiceImpl under different `@GetMapping` annotations.

As suggested by my instructor, I have defined a Dependency Injection as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUserController {

    private final ApplicationUserService applicationUserService; //This variable will work as an object now.

    public ApplicationUserController(ApplicationUserService applicationUserService) {
        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
    }

@GetMapping
//REST OF THE CODE

}
```

I am new to Spring Boot and I tried understanding Dependency Injection in plain English and I understood how it works. I understood that the basic idea is to separate the dependency from the usage. But I am totally confused about how this works in my case.

My Questions:

1. Here ApplicationUserService is an Interface and it's implementation has various methods defined. In the code above, `applicationUserService` now has access to every method from `ApplicationUserServiceImpl`. How did that happen?
2. I want to know how the Object creation works here.
3. Could you tell me the difference between not using DI and using DI in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Answers

1. The interface layer is used for abstraction of the code it will be really helpfull when you want to provide different implementations for it. When you create a instance you are simply creating a ApplicationUserServiceImpl and assigning it into a reference variable of ApplicationUserService this concept is called upcasting. Even though you have created the object of child class/implementation class you can only access the property or methods defined in parent class/interface class. Please refer this for more info
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599259/purpose-of-service-interface-class-in-spring-boot#:~:text=There%20are%20various%20reasons%20why,you%20can%20create%20test%20stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599259/purpose-of-service-interface-class-in-spring-boot#:%7E:text=There%20are%20various%20reasons%20why,you%20can%20create%20test%20stubs).
2. in this example when a applicationusercontroller object is created. The spring engine(or ioc container) will create a object of ApplicationUserServiceImpl (since there is a single implementation of the interface ) and returns to controller object as a constructor orgument which you assign to the refrence variable also refer the concept called IOC(Invertion of control)
3. as explained in the previous answer the spring will take care of object creation (object lifecycle)rather than you explsitly doing it. it will make the objects loosely coupled. In this the controll of creating the instances is with spring .
   The non DI way of doing this is
   private ApplicationUserService applicationUserService = new ApplicationUserServiceImpl()

Hope I have answered your questions

Comment: If in case I used the new keyword to create object of ApplicationUserServiceImpl, that'll work the same way as the current DI is working but in the case of creating an object with a new keyword, I would be required to do the same everywhere but in the code I did above took care of all object creation of ApplicationUserServiceImpl. Could you tell me how that happened? I mean I know Spring takes care of the object creation in this case but how does Spring achieve that?

Comment: How ever this link might make you understand the concept https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring

Comment: I feel to understand that you need to learn the spring framework where we provide xmlbased bean configuration. In springboot the ioc engine searches for the bean/componet/service class in the provided path by default project's main package and creates the object of that type and passes it to the constructor

Comment: Can you please give a upvote if I have resolved your doubt

Answer (score 0):

this analogy may make you understand better consider an example, wherein you have the ability to cook. According to the IoC principle(principal which is the basis of DI), you can invert the control, so instead of you cooking food, you can just directly order from outside, wherein you receive food at your doorstep. Thus the process of food delivered to you at your doorstep is called the Inversion of Control.
You do not have to cook yourself, instead, you can order the food and let a delivery executive, deliver the food for you. In this way, you do not have to take care of the additional responsibilities and just focus on the main work.
Now, that you know the principle behind Dependency Injection, let me take you through the types of Dependency Injection

Comment: Analogy wise I have understood IoC. The best example I came across in the internet was this: 

When you get married.. You have lost control! :D That's quite obvious! Before you were married, you had all the control with you. Now when you divorce, you have inverted the control and you have the control back! :D Funny right? Is this what Inversion of Control means?

Comment: Yah its funny :D